# Configure hadoop/hbase in fully-distributed mode

Tags: hadoop, hbase, distributed-database, nosql

I'm new in Hbase and I need to do some experiments with it in fully distributed mode. I am using ubuntu.

I want create a cluster with two nodes (a master and a slave) and according to what I read, HBase runs under a Hadoop Distributed File System which I need to have both properly configured.

I've tried to follow some tutorials on the Internet but I can't run Hbase in distributed mode properly. I think the problem is in the hadoop and hbase configuration.

Does anyone have Hbase running in fully distributed mode?

Can you tell me all the steps should I follow? And correctly setup hadoop and hbase configurations? Or even if there is some easier way to use Hadoop / HBase...

Comment: HBase installation will be a breeze if you use Cloudera Manager or Apache Ambari depending on whether you are using HDP or CDH. I would not recommend you to do a manual installation.

Answer (score 2):

Try these tutorials for `fully-distributed HBase` configuration:

1. [Fully Distributed HBase](http://jayatiatblogs.blogspot.in/2013/01/hbase-installation-fully-distributed.html)
2. [HBase Installation in Fully Distributed Mode](https://hadooptutorial.info/hbase-installation-fully-distribution-mode/)